# PrimeNg ui-float-label not floating after reactive form patchValue()

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I've **reactive form** for **create and edit action**s. For edit I just `patchValue(data)` on form, works like a charm, **but floating label** from PrimeNg InputText component **don't notice that there was value filled**. When I click on one of the inputs and then blur it, then every inputs are updating the view and all labels are on top.

[image]
[image]

I've tried change detection (view component has it set to `OnPush`), `markAsDirty()`, `markAllAsTouched()` even but labels are still over the input values. No idea how to trigger smth like physical blur on one of the controls (don't want to trigger it in the code on `@ViewChild()` as it looks as wrong solution for me.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Weird thing is that disabling `OnPush` strategy fixes the issue. I've tried to subscribe to form value changes and call change detection there, but it didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can detect changes inside setTimeout after your form is created:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.cdr.markForCheck();
});
```

It seems that we need to listen for some event to run detection after a form with floating labels is ready, but can't find anything proper.

Answer (score 0):

Set "p-filled" class when Input field has value

```html
<input type="text" id="control_name" pInputText formControlName="control_name"
 [ngClass]="{'p-filled': ( formGroup_name.get(control_name)?.value !== '' )}"
>
<label for="control_name">input label</label>
```